# Workaround for notserializable exception when converting Scala map to Java Map

Tags: java, scala

As described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8911), Scala Maps that are wrapped as Java Maps are not serializable because `scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper` is not serializable.

This issue was fixed in Scala 2.12, but I have to use 2.11 for various reasons.
So what is a good workaround for converting a Scala Map to a Java Map without having this serialization error? I have no choice but to return a java map from this function.

My code looks like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter

def doSomethingCool(): util.Map[String, String] = {

    // ... Cool processing here ...
    // Return results as a Java Map
    myScalaMap.asJava
}
```

I feel like there should be a simple way to work around this issue, but I haven't been able to figure it out...

Comment: Just copy the data using a `foreach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to copy a wrapped map with the `java.util.HashMap`'s copy constructor.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter

def doSomethingCool(): util.Map[String, String] = {

    // ... Cool processing here ...
    // Return results as a Java Map
    new java.util.HashMap[String, String](myScalaMap.asJava)
}
```